# imageWithCGImage not being released or is trapped by Cache similar to imageNamed, any work around for generating dynamic images?

Tags: caching, crash, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm generating UIImages with a bit-bucket, creating them on the fly and swapping the UIImageView's image.  Is there a way to edit the UIImageView's Image directly?  (ie. change the color of a specific pixel, without removing the UIImage from the UIImageView, and get it to redraw.)

Currently, I'm flushing the UIImage and using imageWithCGIImage to make a new one, and assigning it to the UIImageView.  This works.  Shows no MemLeaks.  But on the iPhone (3Gs) after about 100 image replacements, CRASHES.  Cache'n issue?  The memory summation seems to be hitting the phone's limit if cache not releasing, however, Simulator does not show memory consumption with each image swap.  Stays flatlined without leaks.

Note:  topologyImage array is the RGBA pixel-bucket.  The REF variables are not released.  Every attempt to do so, crashes next call.  Without, Instruments reports no leaks.

=========

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef=CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaLast;
CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent=kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
CGDataProviderRef provider=CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,topologyImage,(I*I*4),NULL);
CGImageRef imageRef=CGImageCreate(I,I,8,4*8,4*I,colorSpaceRef,bitmapInfo,provider,NULL,false,renderingIntent);

UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
if( IMG[NDXtopo].vw ) {
    [IMG[NDXtopo].vw setImage:img];
    }
else {
    IMG[NDXtopo].vw=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [master.view addSubview:IMG[NDXtopo].vw];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you should release your references, especially the CGImageRef since the imageWithCGImage doesn't take ownership of the CGImage but rather seems to copy the data internally.

The docs on this are quite unclear, but from what I have found in my testing if I don't release CGImageRefs and CGDataProviderRefs it will eventually cause the application to get memory warnings... and then crash.

Not sure why you would have a crash, but in doing a quick test with:

```
UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
int I = 128;
unsigned char *topologyImage = malloc(I*I*4*sizeof(unsigned char));

for(int i=0; i<I*I*4; i++)
{
  topologyImage[i] = 100;
}

for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef=CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaLast;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent=kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGDataProviderRef provider=CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,topologyImage,(I*I*4),NULL);
    CGImageRef imageRef=CGImageCreate(I,I,8,4*8,4*I,colorSpaceRef,bitmapInfo,provider,NULL,false,renderingIntent);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    view.image = img;
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
}
free(topologyimage);
```

Seems to work just fine for me, so whatever is causing your crash seems to be because of something outside of your example, like for example how you got the image data into the topologyImage

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply.

Comment: ::  Thank you for the speedy reply.  I have made a few changes to your code; free(topologyImage) and I=320, everything worked.  Added the UIImageView to the UIView and CRASH. The imageview was added to the view after its allocation.  Then loop'd through image creations and view.image assignments.  Works fine in simulator.  Crashes on the iPhone.

Comment: Last post.  Ran another test on my code with just the RELEASE()'s added.  The topology was created and with touches chunks of earth are removed.  84 touches removes the entire image and touch 85 regenerates a new topology map.  Prior to the RELEASE()'s it crashed in second map.  With the RELEASE()'s it ran through ten maps and no crash.  Before posting here, I tested with the RELEASE()'s and got the same results.  Could I have done things in the wrong order?  Is it important for colorSpaceRef to be released prior to provider, prior to creating the image?   THANK YOU.

Comment: As far as I know the order should not matter, it is mostly just a habit to release things as early as possible after having done things on the original iPhone that had very constrained memory. So I am nit certain what you were doing that gave a different result.